# position of UITextfield not setting properly

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield

I am making an app i want to set my position of `UITextfield`. but i am stuck in it, it is setting only `vertical position` not `horizontal position`. below is my code and screen shot

```
Msgtextfield.placeholder=@"demo";
CGRect frame = CGRectMake(100,100,10,100);
UILabel * leftView = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
leftView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
self.Msgtextfield.leftView = leftView;
self.Msgtextfield.leftViewMode = UITextFieldViewModeAlways;
self.Msgtextfield.contentVerticalAlignment = UIControlContentVerticalAlignmentCenter;
   self.Msgtextfield.contentHorizontalAlignment=UIControlContentHorizontalAlignmentCenter;
```

[image: i want the text starting from the topleft corner of uitextfield]

Comment: you want to change the position of `UItextfield` cursor `position`

Comment: yeah... i want to change position of uitextfield cursor position

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `CATransform3DMakeTranslation` don't forget to import `Quartzcore framework`

```
 self.Msgtextfield.layer.sublayerTransform=CATransform3DMakeTranslation(5, 0, 0);
```

Comment: i had used but still same origin of text

Comment: change the **tx**-5 into customize your self

Comment: @RameshMuthe -- tanx my friend

Answer (score 1):

```
UITextField.layer.sublayerTransform=CATransform3DMakeTranslation();
```

This line will work ..

Answer (score 0):

Make category class of Textfield.

**UITextField+bgImageset.h**

```
@interface UITextField (bgImageset)
-(CGRect)textRectForBounds:(CGRect)bounds;
-(CGRect)editingRectForBounds:(CGRect)bounds;
```

**UITextField+bgImageset.m**

```
@implementation UITextField (bgImageset)

#pragma clang diagnostic push
#pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Wobjc-protocol-method-implementation"
-(CGRect)textRectForBounds:(CGRect)bounds {

    return CGRectMake(bounds.origin.x+10 , bounds.origin.y ,
                      bounds.size.width - 10 , bounds.size.height );
}
-(CGRect)editingRectForBounds:(CGRect)bounds {
    return [self textRectForBounds:bounds];
}
```

import this class where you want to change cursor position and Change you X position for text-field cursor.